# Optimization in R: Levenberg-Marquardt using nls.lm in minpack.lm: resetting `maxiter' to 1024

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, levenberg-marquardt

I am trying to learn how to work with `nls.lm` in the R library `minpack.lm` by using the Rosenbrock function to see if the algorithm converges to the global minimum at f(x,y) = (1,1). I do so both with and without the analytic Jacobian. In both instances, I get a warning telling me that the algorithm has decided to revert the maximum number of iterations specified in the call to `nls.lm` to 1024:

```
Warning messages:
1: In nls.lm(par = initpar, fn = objective_rosenbrock, jac = gradient_rosenbrock,  :
  resetting `maxiter' to 1024!
2: In nls.lm(par = initpar, fn = objective_rosenbrock, jac = gradient_rosenbrock,  :
  lmder: info = -1. Number of iterations has reached `maxiter' == 1024.
```

The algorithm never quite reaches (1,1) as a result given my initial guess of (-1.2, 1.0). I found the source code for the library on GitHub and the following lines of code are pertinent here:

https://github.com/cran/minpack.lm/blob/master/src/nls_lm.c

```
OS->maxiter = INTEGER_VALUE(getListElement(control, "maxiter"));
if(OS->maxiter > 1024) {
  OS->maxiter = 1024;
  warning("resetting `maxiter' to 1024!");
}
```

Is there any logic to why the maximum number of iterations is capped to 1024? Something with bits and 2^10? I would like to use the library for a different application, but this cap on iterations might prevent that. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: There is a (relatively) new package 'nlsr' that is intended to replace `nls()` with a pure R implementation, and should also be more stable and reliable than, e.g., 'minpack.lm'. I would give it a try -- though it might be slower than 'minpack.lm' for large applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Git blame](https://github.com/cran/minpack.lm/blame/master/src/nls_lm.c#L143) says that this code limiting the max iterations was introduced in version 1.1-0, in 2008. The [NEWS file for the package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/minpack.lm/NEWS) only goes back as far as version 1.1-6. I can't find the code in any public repo other than the one you point to (which is only a CRAN mirror; it doesn't contain any comments/commit messages/etc. from developers that might give us clues.)

Other than contacting the maintainer I think it's going to be hard to figure out what the rationale is for this limit.

I do have some guesses though.

The only places that `maxiter` is actually used in the code are [here](https://github.com/cran/minpack.lm/blob/ece5c92f4f21ff156a2d7733e964e139e57b7085/src/fcn_lmdif.c#L54) and [here](https://github.com/cran/minpack.lm/blob/ece5c92f4f21ff156a2d7733e964e139e57b7085/src/fcn_lmder.c#L65) - in R code, not Fortran or C code, so it seems extremely unlikely that we are dealing with something like a 10-bit unsigned integer type (which seems an unlikely choice in any case). I think the limitation is there because we also have a buffer defined for holding trace information [here](https://github.com/cran/minpack.lm/blob/ece5c92f4f21ff156a2d7733e964e139e57b7085/src/minpack_lm.h#L20):

```c
  double rsstrace[1024];
```

which, as you can see, is hard-coded to a length of 1024. Presumably bad things would happen if we tried to stuff 1025 iterations'-worth of tracing information into this array ...

My suggestions:

- change all instances of '1024' in the code to something larger and see what happens. There are only four:

```
$ find . -type f -exec grep -Hn 1024 {} \;
./src/nls_lm.c:141:    if(OS->maxiter > 1024) {
./src/nls_lm.c:142:      OS->maxiter = 1024;
./src/nls_lm.c:143:      warning("resetting `maxiter' to 1024!");
./src/minpack_lm.h:20:  double rsstrace[1024];
```

- it would be best to `#define MAXITER 2048` (or whatever) in `src/minpack_lm.h` and use that instead of the numerical value.
- Contact the maintainer (`maintainer("minpack.lm")`) and ask them about this issue.